# JavaMail : Connects on some machines and errors in some other machines

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail to read the java emails from gmail account. The code is working pretty fine on my Windows 7 machine. But, the same code errors out (below mentioned is the error) after running on Windows 2k8 machine. Absolutely no change in the code. 
Can some one please help to know the reason for this failure?

Error :

```
   javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:618)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at com.vmware.cmpaas.uiqe.util.EmailUtil.getActivationLink(EmailUtil.java:42)
    at Temp_Test.main(Temp_Test.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:109)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:585)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Temp_Test.main(Temp_Test.java:18)
```

Comment: What is causing the NullPointerException? Are all the configurations and resources also the identical same?

Comment: Yep ... Same code on the Windows 7 machine where it is working fine...

Comment: See the JavaMail FAQ for [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the FAQ link. But, I have already tried out that and it was not helpful. I have enabled the debug mode even in the code. I see a message : "DEBUG: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect; " and followed by the trace I mentioned in the 1st post.

Comment: This is not just about the code. Are your firewall / ... settings identical? What if you are trying to reach something what is blocked by your configuration on the other machine?

Comment: Hi, I have my firewall disabled already. Same code and trying to fetch email from gmail. So, I don't think there is an issue with the destination host (gmail) for any settings. I am wondering, if I need to enable any particular feature in windows 2008 for imap or pop3. Any clue?